# Check to see if the given web address is blocking visitors ip

Tags: javascript, php, html, ip, block

I want to make an web application where a user inputs a web address and click to a submit button. Now what my application does it checks if the given web address is blocking his/her ip address. Can you please help me to make this web application? I want to use php and javascript.

Basic PHP code and HTML structure:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['check_status'] ) ) {

    $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );
    extract( $_POST );

    if ( empty( $web_addr ) ) {
        $error = "Web address is required.";
    }

    if ( !isset( $error ) ) {
        function checkIpBlocked() {
            /* I need this code to check */
        }   
    }
}
?>

<h2>Check your ip address is blocked or not</h2>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="web_addr">Enter Web Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="web_addr" placeholder="Enter Web Address">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_ip" value="<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="check_status" value="Check Status">
    <div id="status"><?php if ( isset( $error ) ) { echo $error } ?></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not possible. To be able to check this, you have to be able to receive at the given IP address, which if its not your address, you can't, so you will never receive a response, meaning your app will ALWAYS think the user's IP is blocked 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a reliable way to do that, unless the websites in question give you an API to do that.